# QuickBlox after some time Sender become receiver and receiver become Sender

Tags: ios, quickblox

i am using QuickBlox Simple Chat for how to know how it was working.

In demo ex.2 user first is USER1 and Other is USER2.

After some time USER1 message display in table where the side of USER2 message  and USER2 message is display in side of USER1 messages.

Get a response to the server like this

```
Request finished, response: 
RestResponse:
------
<QBASIHTTPRequest: 0xa288c00>
headers:{
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    Connection = Close;
    "Content-Length" = 106;
    "Content-Type" = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Sat, 05 Oct 2013 05:54:05 GMT";
    "QB-Token-ExpirationDate" = "2013-10-05 07:53:46 UTC";
    "QuickBlox-REST-API-Version" = "0.1.1";
    Server = "nginx/1.0.15";
    Status = "422 Unprocessable Entity";
    "X-Rack-Cache" = "invalidate, pass";
    "X-Request-Id" = c70e07ac0a8571253773cde59c23676c;
    "X-Runtime" = "0.223264";
    "X-UA-Compatible" = "IE=Edge,chrome=1";
}
body:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<errors>
  <error>No one can receive the message</error>
</errors>

error:
```